# Wants to deploy chaincode written in golang to aws cloud

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, chaincode

I have written my chaincode in golang and now I want to deploy it on a cloud (aws).

Is the golang file enough to deploy it or do I need to package additional files for deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Just the golang file. Is going to ask your for the dependencies also, but you can get them on the machine that you will deploy the chaincode.